# Combine multiple array based on composite key in xquery

Tags: xquery

I am facing an issue while combining element array based on two key that is docNo and item_no in xquery version 1.0
Below is the given xml sample input and output

sample XML Request:

```
<text>
<element>
    <docNo>11111</docNo>
    <item_no>001</item_no>
    <text_line>SUPER  PROFILE</text_line>
</element>
<element>
    <docNo>1111</docNo>
    <item_no>001</item_no>
    <text_line>TOP SPOTS</text_line>
</element>
<element>
    <docNo>1111</docNo>
    <item_no>002</item_no>
    <text_line>SUPER PROFILE</text_line>
</element>
<element>
    <docNo>1111</docNo>
    <item_no>002</item_no>
    <text_line>TOP SPOTS</text_line>
</element>
<element>
    <docNo>2222</docNo>
    <item_no>002</item_no>
    <text_line>PROILE</text_line>
</element>
```

output :

```
<text>
<element>
    <docNo>11111</docNo>
    <item_no>001</item_no>
    <text>
        <text_line>SUPER  PROFILE</text_line>
        <text_line>TOP SPOTS</text_line>
    </text>
</element>
<element>
    <docNo>11111</docNo>
    <item_no>002</item_no>
    <text>
        <text_line>SUPER  PROFILE</text_line>
        <text_line>TOP SPOTS</text_line>
    </text>
</element>
<element>
    <docNo>2222</docNo>
    <item_no>002</item_no>
    <text>
        <text_line>PROFILE</text_line>
    </text>
</element>
```

I am using distinct-values in but it is merging both with item_no 001 and 002.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XQuery 3 you would use the group by clause with two grouping keys:

```
/*/element { node-name(.)  } {
    for $e at $pos in element
    group by $dn := $e/docNo, $in := $e/item_no
    order by head($pos)
    return
        <element>
        {
            head($e) ! (docNo, item_no),
            <text>
            {
                $e/text_line
            }
            </text>
        }
        </element>
}
```

In XQuery 1 you can use `distinct-values` on a key concatenated from the two elements:

```
/*/element { node-name(.)  } {
    for $key in distinct-values(for $e in element return concat($e/docNo, '|', $e/item_no))
    let $group := element[concat(docNo, '|', item_no) = $key]
    return 
        <element>
        {
            $group[1]/(docNo | item_no),
            <text>
            {
                $group/text_line
            }
            </text>
        }
        </element>
}
```